# Argument 1: cannot convert from 'void' to 'System.Action'

Tags: c#

So I've been messing around with c#, and lately, I've been trying to experiment with asynchronous stuff. I tried doing that here, the intention was for this code to generate the text "hi" before it generated the text "hey", despite Console.WriteLine("hi") being after Console.WriteLine("hey"). Ideally, the code would have started the task to print "hey" while it was printing "hi", but I keep getting the same error message preventing it from working. Any help would be appreciated.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Media;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace consolenetfarmeowrk
{
    public class Program
    {
        public void Bruh(int x, string y)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(y);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(x);
        }
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var mc = new Program();
            Task t = new Task(mc.Bruh(5000, "hey"));     
            Console.WriteLine("hi");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`mc.Bruh(5000, "hey")` calls the function, and you are passing its result to `new Task`.

You need to pass the Task constructor a piece of code that knows how to call the function... an anonymous delegate would be a good choice: `new Task(delegate { mc.Bruh(5000, "hey"); });`

Comment: Even so, if the Task is not started....

Comment: Thank you so much! I added a t.Start(); right below it and it worked just as I wanted!